# Problems building the JBoss Hibernate tutorial

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, build

I have heard a lot of good things about the hibernate frame work, so i decided to try it out. I have downloaded the tutorial files from [JBoss website](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-preface.html#d0e94) unzipped but when i am trying to build the project using the mvn compile command.

i am getting build errors (see below the maven debug output).

I have tried to purge the subprojects but it didnt work. it seem like there is a problem with the org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final

Any advice??

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Hibernate Getting Started Guide Tutorials ......... SUCCESS [0.025s]
[INFO] Hibernate hbm.xml Tutorial ........................ FAILURE [0.302s]
[INFO] Hibernate Annotations Tutorial .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hibernate JPA Tutorial ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Hibernate Envers Tutorial ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.561s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Apr 02 23:32:43 PDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hibernate-tutorial-hbm: Could not reso
lve dependencies for project org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial-hbm:jar:
3.6.2.Final: Failure to find org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final in htt
p://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will n
ot be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates ar
e forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project hibernate-tutorial-hbm: Could not resolve dependencies for project org
.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial-hbm:jar:3.6.2.Final: Failure to find org
.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was c
ached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the upda
te interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res
olve dependencies for project org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial-hbm:jar
:3.6.2.Final: Failure to find org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final in ht
tp://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will
not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates a
re forced
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:170)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:171)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure
 to find org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/
maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted un
til the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:412)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:164)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure t
o find org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/ma
ven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted unti
l the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:541)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArti
facts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:395)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to fi
nd org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until th
e update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArti
fact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:190)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:430)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hibernate-tutorial-hbm
C:\Program Files\Development\Tutorials\hibernate\jboss.org.hibernate.core>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That version of hibernate does not exist in central at http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/

It does exist in the JBoss repo at https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/

You need to add https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss to your list of repositories to search in either your POM or in your master Maven settings.xml.

You can add this to your POM as shown at http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories, or something like the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>jbosspublic</id>
      <name>JBoss Public</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    ...
  </pluginRepositories>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I belive that all the repsitories should unite! it is the same thing for me to look for the jar or look for the repository.

Comment: That would be nice.  A way I've solved this is to create my own deployment of the Nexus repository management that proxies all the repositories I need.  Then, my POM files only refer to my own repository.  Whenever I need a file from it, it automatically checks all the remote proxied repositories and downloads what I need, then caches it locally (which is great for teams, because your local repository is much faster).